# Extracting comments in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, comments, asp.net-mvc-5

I have all of my controller methods commented like so;

```
/// <summary>
/// Processes the users input form validating wheter it is correct or not. The postage cost is added on in this method, then creates the order using these details
/// </summary>
/// <param name="values">Values entered in form are then taken into the controller</param>
/// <param name="id">Cart ID to be passed through</param>
/// <param name="Address">The user can select which address they want to use</param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

How can I extract all of these comments for documentation?

Using Visual Studio 2015, Asp.net, MVC

Comment: https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB

Comment: Try doxygen: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/

Comment: @Steve I have been told that Visual Studio 2015 has the ability to extract the comments without the need of a plugin, also if that is what you linked me to could you possibly explain why instead of just posting a link?

Comment: You can pull out comments automatically but setting generate XML comments ("XML documentation file") in the build properties pages of your project but this gives you an unwieldy XML file. Tools like doxygen then format that in to something more human-friendly.

Comment: No info on that VS2015 functionality. I have used SandCastle in the past to write help files gathering data from the XML comments as it seems you require.

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful comments, I will look into each of them and see what suits me best